# How to load many-to-many object graphs using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship (for this example "Left" "Right" and "Joinder") and another entity "Satellite" that keys into "Left." It just so happens that Sattelite's FK also has a unique index on it. My goal is to load one Joinder entity, along with its Left and Right entities, using properties on Satellite for a where clause.

I've tried a number of approaches, but my vocabulary for Linq is weak and I don't even really know the terms for what I'm looking for.

```
var joinder = dbContext.Joinders
                .Include(j => j.Left)
                .Include(j => j.Right)
                .Include(j => j.Left.Satellites)
                .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Hubble");
```

This doesn't work because the FirstOrDefault clause doesn't have context of s to analyze the name.

```
var joinder = dbContext.Joinders
                .Include(j => j.Left)
                .Include(j => j.Right)
                .Include(j => j.Left.Satellites)
                .Select(j => j.Left.Satellites)
                .Where(s => s.Name == "Hubble");
```

This doesn't work because the type coming out of Select is `IQueryable<Collection<Satellite>>` which is confusing.

```
var query = from j in dbContext.Joinders
    join l in dbContext.Lefts on j.LeftId equals l.Id
    join r in dbContext.Rights on j.RightId equals r.Id
    join s in dbContext.Satellites on l.Id equals s.LeftId
    where s.Name == "Hubble"
    select j;
```

This query compiles and runs, but returns totally dehydrated objects to me--the Joinder reference I get back has Left and Right properties both null.

```
var query = from j in dbContext.Joinders
    join l in dbContext.Lefts on j.LeftId equals l.Id
    join r in dbContext.Rights on j.RightId equals r.Id
    join s in dbContext.Satellites on l.Id equals s.LeftId
    where s.Name == "Hubble"
    select new Joinder
    {
        Left = l,
        Right = r,
        Left.Satellites = ...?
    };
```

This doesn't appear to work because I can't seem to dereference these property names inside an automatic initializer.

Anyone know how to do this? Essentially I would like to search "entity framework many-to-many deep load" but I guess not everyone else would word it like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var joinder = dbContext.Joinders
    .Include(j => j.Right)
    .Include(j => j.Left.Satellites)
    .FirstOrDefault(j => j.Left.Satellites.Any(s => s.Name == "Hubble"));
```

It returns the first joinder that has at least one satellite with the given name. `.Include(j => j.Left.Satellites)` will include the `Left` entity as well (everything that is on the path to the last property), so that a separate `Include(j => j.Left)` is not necessary.

**Edit**

If you don't want to load the related `Satellites` together with the `Joinder`, just replace `.Include(j => j.Left.Satellites)` by `.Include(j => j.Left)`. The predicate in `FirstOrDefault` (that depends on `Satellite` properties) will still work.

Comment: The include of `Satellites` is not necessary is it? _one Joinder entity, along with its Left and Right entities_. The Select will work without the Include.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, I didn't read the question careful enough. The `Left.Satellites = ...?` in the question's last code snippet looked to me like he wanted to load the satellites as well. I've added a remark to the answer.

Comment: I indeed did not intend to load the Satellite entities, but the conversation resulting from this difference in interpretation is helpful and very illuminating!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var joinders = dbContext.Joinders
                        .Include(j => j.Left)
                        .Include(j => j.Right)
                        .Include(j => j.Left.Satellites)
                        .Where(j => j.Left.Satellites.Any(s => s.Name == "Hubble");
```

This will return All Joinders where any of the Satellites linked to a "Left" has the name "Hubble". 
I know that Left and Right will be eager loaded, but for Satellites, I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting! So in the context of FirstOrDefault, j.Left.Satellites resolves as Satellite and not Collection<Satellite>? It's a little confusing how that would work, but I guess I can't see how else it would work either. Thanks!

Comment: FirstOrDefault is juste like adding Select "Top 1" in Sql. I didn't notice the 's' to Satellites. Check my update